# Problem HTTP POST request with Thingspeak

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet-shield

I am trying to post a tweet using thingspeak but it is not getting posted. Am I missing something in my POST request or something wrong in my code?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

const byte mac [] = {0x00, 0xC2, 0xA2, 0xE6, 0x3D, 0x57};
const int ledPin = 3;

const char webServer [] = "api.thingspeak.com";
const char webFile [] = "/apps/thingtweet/1/statuses/update";
const char apiKey [] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

EthernetClient myClient;

String msg = "This is my tweet";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.println("Connecting to Network");

  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) != 1) {
    Serial.println("Connection Failed");

    while (true) {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      delay(500);
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("Connected to Network");
  }

  // connect to thingstweet server
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(webServer);

  if (myClient.connect(webServer, 80) != 1) {
    Serial.println("Failed to connect to Thingspeak");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Sucessfully connected to ThingsSpeak");
    myClient.stop();
  }

  myClient.print("POST ");
  myClient.print(webFile);
  myClient.println(" HTTP/1.0");
  myClient.print("Host: ");
  myClient.println(webServer);
  myClient.println("Connection: close");
  myClient.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  myClient.print("Content-Length: ");
  myClient.println(msg.length() + 32);
  myClient.println();

  //POST some data
  myClient.print("api_key=");
  myClient.print(apiKey);
  myClient.print("&status=");
  myClient.println(msg);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

---

Raw POST request from reqbin website

```
POST /apps/thingtweet/1/statuses/update HTTP/1.1
Host: api.thingspeak.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 48

api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxS&status=new%20test%20msg
```

---

Raw response from Reqbin

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 14 May 2020 21:24:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800
ETag: W/"6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f57"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: request_method=POST; path=/
X-Request-Id: f9afc383-63d3-4c91-8f15-4d8e4a90f87b
X-Runtime: 0.172584
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.57
Server: nginx/1.9.3 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.57

1
```

Comment: is the arduino able to connect to the internet?

Comment: yes the arduino is connected to the network. Also it is able to connect to the Thingspeak

Comment: It's possibly because your `Content-Length` shouldn't be `msg.length() + 32` but rather `msg.length() + 34` due to the extra CRLF from `myClient.println(msg);`; that CRLF isn't needed though. If fixing that doesn't work, you can also try sending the POST manually with a site like this: https://reqbin.com/req/yjok4snr. To verify that your request is well-formed and that the server responds as expected.

Comment: I have tried changing the content length but it didn't make any difference. Also by sending the POST request manually I am able to tweet. So I think the request is OK. But why doesn't it work with my arduino code?

Comment: When you tested manually, how exact did you get? Did you use the exact same headers, the exact same HTTP 1.0? Speaking of which, try changing that to HTTP 1.1, no reason to use 1.0, I think. Instead of fixing the changing the content length, get rid of the extra CRLF in your POST payload; make that `print()` instead of `println()`. And use the `X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY` header in your request to specify your API key. Then update your question with the current sketch, if no combo of these works.

Comment: I used the exact same header except the HTTP version as the reqbin site didn't let me choose one or atleast I don't know how to specify that (may be in the header??). I have updated the original post with the raw POST request and response. Also when I change the api_key header to X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY I get a HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.

Comment: @TisteAndii but thanks for telling me about reqbin and sending the response manually. I learnt something new

Comment: @Zaffresky Sure, you're welcome. The Bad Request response seems to originate from a HTTP 1.1 server, perhaps Thingspeak has disabled HTTP 1.0 support. That's why I'd suggest you try making both requests exactly the same; that is, make **your Arduino code** send the exact same hard-coded string as the one from reqbin that has been proven to work. Once you have that working on Arduino, then slowly substitute stuff back in, like your `Connection` header and then the calculated `Content-Length`, etc. Good luck.